# How would you change a float by a random amount within a range in Python?

Tags: python, random

Below is a list of float in an input file called 'inputfile'
I want to loop through each float and randomise it by ± 0.100. How would I go about doing this?

```
 0.08777767595196
 0.41688405291929
 1.90493522025702
 -0.44512262940079
 -1.68572227053594
 -0.19769851139757
 0.61588125474274
 2.98863319423069
 -0.78312326907806
 -2.73208403405514
 -0.36006068363418
```

Comment: First thing would be to clearly specify what you mean by "randomize". Do you mean toss a coin and add or substract 0.1 ? Generate a random number between -0.1 and 0.1 and add this for each value? For the latter, with which distribution ? uniform or normal, for instance ?

Comment: Take a look at this part of the random module: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions

Comment: for the workflow, if the file is not too large (is it a thousand or a million values?) you can either read everything then loop on it (or better, use list comprehension), or you can read by "batches" if this is large, to avoid keeping too many things in memory.

Comment: I mean generate a random number between -0.1 and 0.1 and add this for each value, sorry for my question being unclear!

Answer (score 0):

```
input = open("inputfile", "r").readlines()
import random
noise = 0.1
output = [float(element) + random.random() * noise  * 2 - noise  for element in input ]
print(output )
```

output is the list you are looking for and input your input list.

If your file is too big to store two array you can modify directly your input file like this:

```
noise = 0.1    
for i in range(len(input)):
    input[i] = float(input[i]) + random.random() * noise  * 2 - noise
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np

txtFloatNumbers = np.loadtxt("inputfile.txt", delimiter=" ")

for i, element in enumerate(txtFloatNumbers):
    txtFloatNumbers[i] = element + np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1)
```

Comment: wouldn't `txtFloatNumbers += np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, size=txtFloatNumbers.shape)` be easier and faster than the for loop?

Comment: @Sam Mason I assumed you were absolutely right, but just checked and your solution is roughly 0.03503 ns quicker for a txt with 10000+ float numbers.

Comment: you're measuring something else; retiring a single CPU instruction takes ~0.1 nano second!   I get ~30ms for your code and ~70µs (i.e. ~500x faster) using my suggestion of numpy's vectorisation